# I have a problem with Zoho Integration (JS SDK)

Tags: javascript, crm, zoho

I run the application through web tabs and my site loads in iframe.
The first page contains the files: 
https://live.zwidgets.com/js-sdk/1.0.5/ZohoEmbededAppSDK.min.js and my custom file app.js.
His code:

```
ZOHO.embeddedApp.on("PageLoad",function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
})

ZOHO.embeddedApp.init();
```

everything is fine here. The "PageLoad" event is running.

After a certain business logic I redirect the page location.href="some url of my site". This page contains the files: https://live.zwidgets.com/js-sdk/1.0.5/ZohoEmbededAppSDK.min.js and my custom file app-second.js. This file contains the same code:

```
ZOHO.embeddedApp.on("PageLoad",function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
})

ZOHO.embeddedApp.init();
```

but the "PageLoad" event does not occur. Why?
The "PageLoad" event is executed only once? At the first opening of Zoho CRM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can understand that the method pageload is not executed after you have performed the page redirection.

Unfortunately, Zoho object wont be resolved in the other pages and it will be available only in the page which you have registered in the developer console.

We follow Single Page Application approach, so it won't be possible for you to retrieve CRM information in other pages.

As a workaround you can hide and show different sections based on your business logic.